# Finding the first and third quartile of a box plot

Tags: statistics

I am a bit confused right now because I am doing some practice box plot questions and I came across this particular one.

Given the data 1,2,3,4,5,6 I found the following:

Median: 3.5

Minimum: 1

Maximum: 6

First quartile: 2

Third quartile: 5

However, this is incorrect and the answer key has the first quartile as 1.75 and the third as 5.25, can someone explain to me how those numbers appeared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the example I found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile) with $6$ elements looked like this:

Ordered Data Set: $7, 15, 36, 39, 40, 41$. As there are an even number of data points, all three methods give the same results(You can find the methods in my link) $\rightarrow Q_1=15, Q_2=37,5, Q_3=40$. As you can see, $Q_1$ is the second element, $Q_2$ is the median itself, and $Q_3$ is the fifth element.

In your case, your set: $1,2,3,4,5,6 \rightarrow Q_1= 2, Q_2= 3,5, Q_3= 5$, from the same logic.

Your solution seems fine!

Comment: Thanks ! Must be a typo in the solutions then, I'll have to bring this up with my professor when I have class.

Comment: Sure, answer keys are not always reliable. It is a very good thing, if you mark the mistakes.